# Why this code is not working for sum of even integers?

Tags: c++11

I am trying to find the sum of even integers, but it is not working. It only works for sum of integers after removing the `if` condition.

```
main()
{

int number, sum, upperlimit;

number=1;
sum=0;
std :: cout << "Please enter the number of digits:";
std :: cin  >> upperlimit;

while(number<=upperlimit)
{   
    if(number%2==0)

    {
    sum = sum + number;
    number = number + 1;    
    }
}   

std :: cout << "sum of 1st " << upperlimit <<" Even digits is:" << sum;
}
```

When I am entering the digits not going any where.

Comment: infinite loop..

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(number%2==0)

    {
    sum = sum + number;
    number = number + 1;    
    }
```

Having the `number+=1`condition inside that `if`means that it will only move on if the number is even. So once you reach `1`, for example, it will stay as a `1` for ever.

```
main()
{

int number, sum, upperlimit;

number=1;
sum=0;
std :: cout << "Please enter the number of digits:";
std :: cin  >> upperlimit;

while(number<=upperlimit)
{   
    if(number%2==0)

    {
    sum = sum + number;

    }
    number = number + 1;

}   

std :: cout << "sum of 1st " << upperlimit <<" Even digits is:" << sum;
}
```

Comment: Remeber to mark is as an answer if it solved your problem as well as upvote it if it was useful! @HassanSiddiqui